# C# WPF Querying multiple tables with Ado.Net

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, ado.net, foreign-key-relationship

I am trying to make a small project in C# WPF and i'm facing the following issue:

I have a database with multiple tables, one of them is named "Person" and has a bunch of attributes(name, age etc), one of the attributes is "CompanyId"(it represents the company the Person is working for) and is a foreign key to the "Company" table.
The "Company" table has an Id and a Name as attributes.

I am trying to display the Person's attributes in a textblock when i select the person's name from a listbox. The issue i'm facing is when i am trying to display an attribute(from Person table) that's is a foreign key to another table(CompanyId->Company)

Here's a part of the code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand scmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                scmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Person WHERE Id=@PId";
                scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PId", lstContactList.SelectedIndex + 1);
                SqlDataReader dr = scmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    txtbFirstName.Text = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
                    txtbLastName.Text = dr["LAstName"].ToString();
                    txtbCompany.Text = dr["Company"].ToString();
                }
```

How can i display the attribute "Name" from the Company table so that it reflects the Company where the selected person works for?

Comment: you need to do a [join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your scmd.CommandText should be:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Person p 
join dbo.Company c ON p.CompanyId = c.CompanyId
WHERE Id=@PId
```

Answer (score 0):

try this updates

```
int companyId=0;
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
     conn.Open();
     SqlCommand scmd = conn.CreateCommand();
     scmd.CommandText = "SELECT *,CompanyName FROM dbo.Person p join dbo.Company c ON p.CompanyId = c.CompanyId WHERE Id=@PId";
     scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PId", lstContactList.SelectedIndex + 1);
     SqlDataReader dr = scmd.ExecuteReader();
     if(dr.Read())
     {
          txtbFirstName.Text = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
          txtbLastName.Text = dr["LAstName"].ToString();
          txtbCompany.Text=int.Parse(dr["CompanyName "].ToString());
     }
     conn.Close();
}
```

hope it helps you

Comment: I have used the query in the first comment. Thank you!